# Problem filling rectangle with a TikZ pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am trying to add a pattern-striped background to a rectangle, but the PDF generated with PDFLatex produces a couple of completely black rectangles instead of the ones filled in with the pattern. The following code is taken form the answer to the question [Using form-only patterns with variable: possible TikZ bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84091/using-form-only-patterns-with-variable-possible-tikz-bug).

TikZ code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\tikzset{
    slope/.code={\edef\slope{#1}},
    slope/.default=0.9, slope
}

\makeatletter

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{stripes}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}} {
    \foreach \i in {0.1, 0.3,...,0.9} {
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\i cm}{0cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm - \i cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm - \i cm+ 0.1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\i cm - 0.1cm}{0cm}}
        \pgfpathclose%
        \pgfusepath{fill}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\i cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm - \i cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm - \i cm - 0.1cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0cm}{\i cm + 0.1cm}}
        \pgfpathclose%
        \pgfusepath{fill}
    }
}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\tikz@pattern@color,\slope]{slant lines}
    {\pgfpoint{-.1mm/\slope}{-.1mm}}
    {\pgfpoint{1.1mm/\slope}{1.1mm}}
    {\pgfpoint{1mm/\slope}{1mm}}{
        \pgfsetlinewidth{0.4pt}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1mm/\slope}{-.1mm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1.1mm/\slope}{1.1mm}}
        \pgfsetstrokecolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[pattern=stripes, pattern color=red] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
    \fill[pattern=slant lines, pattern color=blue, slope=0.3] (5,0) rectangle (10,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is shown in the following picture:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is fine on my end with Package: tikz 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142).

Comment: I will try to update the package, my current version is: tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76), the one that comes packaged with Debian Wheezy (stable).